# React-native Xcode build fails -> 'RCTAssert.h file not found'

Tags: react-native

I did exactly the steps which are described here in the React-native getting started guide:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

When I open the Project and build it, the build fails:

> RCTAssert.h file not found' in MyProjectNameTests.m .

What am I missing?

Here are the steps from the getting started guide:

> **Requirements**
>
> OS X - This repo only contains the iOS (7+) implementation right now,
>   and Xcode only runs on Mac.
>
> Xcode 6.3 or higher is recommended.
>
> Homebrew is the recommended way to install io.js, watchman, and flow.
>
> Install io.js 1.0 or newer. io.js is the modern version of Node.
>
> Install nvm with its setup instructions here. Then run `nvm install
>   iojs-v2 && nvm alias default iojs-v2`, which installs the latest
>   compatible version of io.js and sets up your terminal so that typing
>   node runs io.js. With nvm you can install multiple versions of Node
>   and io.js and easily switch between them.
>
> New to npm?
>
> `brew install watchman`. We recommend installing watchman, otherwise
>   you might hit a node file watching bug.
>
> `brew install flow`. If you want to use flow. We recommend
>   periodically running `brew update && brew upgrade` to keep your
>   programs up-to-date.
>
> **Quick Start**
>
> ```
> npm install -g react-native-cli
>
> react-native init AwesomeProject
> ```
>
> In the newly created folder AwesomeProject/
>
> Open AwesomeProject. xcodeproj and hit run in Xcode. Open index.ios.js
>   in your text editor of choice and edit some lines. Hit cmd+R in your
>   iOS simulator to reload the app and see your change!

Comment: Can you add the steps to this question? If the link goes down, nobody can access it.

Comment: Same issue here. Worked fine with react 0.9

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The test application can't find the header because it's not in the header search path.

In the left hand file list, hit the top left "folder" icon, then select your application at top left. In this case "AwesomeProject".

To the right of that, where the application icon appears, hold down to change to AwesomeProjectTests.

On the right side, click on the 'Build settings' tab.

Then scroll down to Header Search Paths and change "$(SRCROOT)/node_modules/react-native/React" to "$(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/react-native/React".

The app should now compile.

Comment: It worked, thanks! Just to clear things up (cause I had to search a little bit): After hitting the top left 'folder' icon and after selecting (in this case) "Awesome Project" the Button we have to click is at the top left corner of the editor area of XCode.

It has the same name like our Project. After changing it to OurProjectTests, we have to choose 'Build Settings'. From there under 'Search Paths' we find Header search paths and go on like @stef explained.

Comment: In earlier versions of the cli the .xcodeproject file got saved in the same directory as node_modules. Now they put it in the iOS folder (& it seems they forgot to change the header search paths). Also if we create a react-native project the cli shows us the wrong path for the .xcodeproject file (not updated too).

Comment: To add to this for any latecomers 3 years later: I was getting the same error when building in Release mode, and it turned out that in Xcode, my header search paths included a library I was no longer using. Additionally, that library had some outdated references in the project navigator directory list - both in LIbraries and in Recovered Preferences. Removing all of these allowed the project to build to device.

Comment: I am getting a similar, not identical, message: "'React/RCTAssert.h' file not found" (this is the include statement, with a "React/" prefix.

Looking at my search path, I have your suggested path. The strange thing is that the same build worked before, stopped working now (what I changed since then was to add fonts to the build, which doesn't seem related). Any idea?

Comment: ... well, after the initial frustration of something that worked and stopped to work, I closed Xcode, reopened it, and things are back to normal... Strange? Or buggy?

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue as daniel but I already have the right path in xcode ...

0.10.0 is my version

Comment: Ah I was too stupid to read @stef 's solution right. It's critically important to  select the TEST TARGET in the xcode window (left to "general"). The normal target path is correct.

Answer (score 2):

It's an issue in 0.10.0, and it has been fixed just now.

You need to re-generate your project. Refer to this PR: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/2474

Answer (score 1):

seeing same issue here and it seems react-native is latest on 0.10.0, i was using 0.8.0 and was running fine. May be to disable the test target for now?

Comment: try @stef 's solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Before testing any option from the above mentioned solutions, just clean your xCode and build the app again. That helped me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (I just had changed my apple ID password). I needed to redo the [code signing configuration](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device#2-configure-code-signing).

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me on a React Native project.

I rolled back my code to a version that I knew built successfully and *still* got this error. How is this even possible? There's two hours of my life I'll never get back. I write this here on the chance I save you from the same fate.

In my case when I jump from my IDE in which I code my react-native project over to Xcode I open it from Spotlight.

[image: Opening Xcode from Spotlight]

At this point it is *so* easy to click the wrong icon on the right hand side. I accidentally clicked on the Xcodeproj file instead of the Xcworkspace. Easy to do, once it loads everything looks exactly the same, I was none the wiser.

The only indication that something had gone wrong was the build errors. Worse this error looks like a dependency management issue sending you down completely the wrong path in a resolution attempt.

This is not just a React Native specific issue, but something all Cocoapod users need to remember.

Answer (score -1):

**ADD the React Path to Podfile**

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'YourProject' do
...
pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native'

end

target 'RNFirebaseTests' do
...
pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native'

end
```